# Phonegap App detect language and country

Tags: cordova

I want to program an multilingual / multicountry app and I would like to know what is the best solution to detect the system language of the device and the country, where the user is opening the App in Phonegap?

The App will be a search engine and the information is country specific. What means, that if someone opens the App in Spain, then the App need to select the country ES and if the device has as selected ES as language, then the ES GUI should be loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at the docs? There is a section on just this - Globalization: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#Globalization

You may also find useful [cordova-plugin-sim](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim) which provides `countryCode` associated with SIM card.

Globalization plugin provides values which are modified by phone user (user preferences), while cordova-plugin-sim provides values set by the SIM card carrier (user cannot change them).

Comment: Hey this is great stuff. That means, that this can be my solution: globalization.getLocaleName :-)

Comment: Lets see if for example the locale is empty and there is only the language displayed .. do yu thing is good option to use the IP to cann a service of mine and get the Country iso code? Is the IP the right value ... or should I use Lat/Lon ?

Comment: I'd say maybe give them the option to tell you what locale they want to use. My opinion obviously.

Comment: Is it possible to detect a change of locale in settings? Some event supported by OS and Cordova?

Comment: Afaik there is no event change fired for this. I'd imagine in the real world this is pretty rare. You could simply check yourself every time the app launches, or perhaps every 5 minutes using setInterval.